# Tag synonym request:  [teaching] -> [education]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have seperate [education](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/education) and [teaching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tags.

It seems that [teaching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/teaching) with 4 questions, and [education](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/education) with 6 questions are essentially the same.

Also there is the [children](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/children) tag that may factor into this somewhere.

**Edit:** It seems [children](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/children) are dead, so don't worry about that.

Comment: [education] is a more general term than [teaching] (it also includes concepts like learning, mentoring, school administration, testing, and others). So it would probably be better to have [teaching] -> [education], rather than have any question tagged [education] appear with [teaching]. Alternatively, we could add other education-related tags and either keep [education] and [teaching] as separate tags or blacklist [education] (though I do not recommend either of these alternative approaches). As for [children], this concept overlaps education but surely not enough for a tag synonym.

Comment: [tag:children] got killed. Teaching can be remapped to education.

Comment: There we go. edited to, teaching -> education.

Comment: @jokerdino "children got killed" sounds like a massacre.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS It's a joke. No children were hurt during the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked so nicely, I went through the [teaching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tag and retagged the questions as relevant. Now, we shall only have a [education](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/education) tag.

Comment: That's one way of doing it, thanks.

Comment: Generally, if there are less than 20 questions in a tag, retagging is preferred. And it was a mere 4 questions anyway. :)

Comment: These are now synonyms